# Liquibase causing PostgreSQL DB Lock - Microservices running as a pod in AKS

Tags: postgresql, locking, liquibase

We are multiple microservices(With Liquibase) running on Azure AKS cluster as a pod.

Frequently we have noticed DB locks and pods will crash as it will fail in health checks.

Is there a way to overcome this scenario as it is impacting a lot. We have to manually unlock DB table, so that pod will start.

In one of the logs, I’ve noticed below error

I believe, it needs to be handled from Application(Springboot).

Comment: You reference a 'below error', but did not include the error message.

Comment: Hi James, thank you. From pod logs, I can see error like waiting for change lock.

Comment: Before DB lock, I’ve noticed this error in logs—-com.mchange.v2.async.thread pool asynchronous.deadlockdetector —- Apparent Deadlock - creating emergency thread

Answer (score 0):

You can write a piece of code that executes at the start of application that will release the lock if found. Then the database connection won't fail.
Currently using the same for our environment.

Comment: Hi Pavan, Thank you. When application starts, before Liquibase acquires DB lock - you have added a code to release lock? Currently manually DB team is releasing dB lock. Not sure how this can be handled by application

Comment: We don't know why DB lock is happening. Is there any parameters we need to define at application level or it’s because of misconfiguration.